# How to get a video to play only once?

Tags: wordpress, video, cookies

I have a video featured on my home page [Click Here](http://www.challenge-the-box.com), however it will drive my visitors nuts if it plays every single time they visit. How can I go about getting it to play for the first time they visit? The theme's developers said it will involve a lot of code and wouldn't assist me further.

Thanks!

Comment: well like you have tagged the post you could load the video by js/php if no cookie is set, it would actually be easy to do if you know js or php.

Comment: It also depends if you want the video to play fully before adding it in the "watched" video.